# Extracting points with polygon in R

Tags: r, extract, polygon, geospatial

I'm trying to extract points by a polygon using the 'sp' package function 'over'

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
#my polygon plgn (many polygon features in one)
plot(plgn)
proj4string(plgn) = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
#giving spatial reference to point data d
coordinates(d) <- ~X+Y
proj4string(d) = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
#USE overlay (there are many NAs)
overlay=d[!is.na(over(d, plgn)),]
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an ERROR

```
Error in d[!is.na(over(d, plgn)), ] : 
matrix argument not supported in SpatialPointsDataFrame selection
```

Any idea?? Is it because my polygon contains 100s of features?

Comment: Have you tried running that line from the inside out? e.g., check what `over(d, plgn)` returns, then look at `is.na(over(d, plgn))`. Do their results make sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `plgn` is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, and as such, `is.na(over(d, plgn))` returns a logical matrix. This cannot be used to subset your `SpatialPoints*`. You can do the following to convert the logical matrix to a vector that the subsetting operation can accommodate:

```
d[complete.cases(over(d, plgn)), ]
```